# Atom Editor is not working on my computer, How can I resolve this to start programming

Tags: python, html, atom-editor

I opened the atom to write python code after a long time but it is showing like this

[image]

I have uninstalled and re-installed but did not worked
I also restarted my PC

I cannot do anything with atom, please suggest the method so that it works.

[image]
PYCharm is also not working

Comment: That's the developer tools. Try Ctrl+Shift+I

Comment: Not working for me

Comment: Even I uninstalled and reinstalled the software, still this screen emerges when I run atom

Comment: Have you removed all data files like cache and such when you reinstalled?

Comment: Yes, may be a problem with my computer. I think I have to reinstall windows

Comment: Have you tried `atom --clear-window-state`?